# Adding functions to openCV's source code - specifically features2d - ORB

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, orb

I've spent the last two days trying to figure out how to add functions to openCV's ORB.

I have figured out how to add parameters and modify current functions but can't seem to add a new function.

My ultimate goal would be to have an orb feature detector and be able to call a public function:

cv::Ptr p = new cv::OrbFeatureDetector()
p->compute(~~) ;

I would like to be able to call an additional function like:
p->doSomething();

Is this possible to do without having to make any additional files, namespaces etc ?

or do I HAVE to stick with the traditional setter / getter approach? - I'm working using C++ if that makes any difference.

Comment: It's easy enough, if you plan on recompiling OpenCV after you've made your changes. Then you can do whatever you want. Alternatively, you could just write a free function to perform the operation you want. Could you clarify your example? It's hard to see why you want to do this -- it's certainly an odd request.

Comment: do you really need to modify the opencv codebase ? try to avoid that, as you will have to redistribute the whole modified opencv version to make it run elsewhere. usually layering or inheritance in your own code does the trick.